# How to add JSON array to elasticsearch using Postman

Tags: elasticsearch, postman

I have tried to add sample data set using postman as following way,

```
POST URL:  http://localhost:9200/allData
```

Add to postman body as json

```
{
    "index": "allData",
    "type": "all",
    "id": 1006,
    "body":  {

                    "id": 1006,
                    "url": "https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Principles_of_Management",
                    "title": "Principles of Management",
                    "author": "",
                    "rate": 0,
                    "ratedBy": 0,
                    "datePublished": "2018-01-01T00:00:00",
                    "publishedDate": "2018-01-01"   
    }
}
```

But it is given following error.

> No handler found for uri [/] and method [POST]

Someone please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certain issues with your request:

- Elasticsearch index names cannot have uppercase so in your case it should be **alldata** not **allData**.
- The format of the URL is wrong.

Your URL should be in the below format:

```
http://localhost:9200/{indexname}/{type}/{id}
```

which in your case must be:

```
http://localhost:9200/alldata/all/1006
```

So you should perform a POST request to the above url with the body as:

```
{
   "id": 1006,
   "url": "https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Principles_of_Management",
   "title": "Principles of Management",
   "author": "",
   "rate": 0,
   "ratedBy": 0,
   "datePublished": "2018-01-01T00:00:00",
   "publishedDate": "2018-01-01"   
}
```

Have a look at the [Elasticsearch Reference Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html).

Hope it helps !